# Notation for a function definition

Tags: functions, notation

I came across the following notation in a research paper

> Suppose we have a function $f(x) \in [1,l] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

It is the first time, I am looking such a notation. And the paper is using the same notation for all functions used in it.

Is it same as
$f(x) : [1,l] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

If yes, is it an abuse of notation?

If no, what does the notation mean?

Comment: What a weird notation.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you gave some idea of when the paper was published (decade identification is probably enough -- 1950s, 1960s, 1970s, 1980s, etc.)  and gave the name of the journal. For instance, I would imagine this would be more peculiar if published in Transactions of the AMS in the 1990s than in some mostly unknown journal less than 20 years old.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It is a recent paper, around 2016...

Comment: It must be stressed that $f(x)$ is **not** a function. $f$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the paper you're using, I understand it means that $f$ belongs to the set of all functions defined from the set $[1,l]$ to the set $\mathbb{R}$, to be said,
$$[1,l]\to\mathbb{R} := \{f \text{ function }: f \text{ is defined from $[1,l]$ to $\mathbb{R}$}\}$$
so it works the same way as defining $f$ the usual way, to be said:
$$f\in[1,l]\to\mathbb{R} \equiv f:[1,l]\to\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: @iftiben10 that is not the way you should upvote. Upvotes must be given when you consider a post deserves it, not just for mindlessly earn reputation asking users you upvoted to upvote you in return.

Comment: sorry, brother, I'm a sad person that my question doesn't have many votes thank you for your response.